# How To a autoselect Patient Name field when bed assign to patients in Django

Tags: django

How To assign bed to Patient Django?

when I try to assign bed to Patient at that time in bedconfig automatically select Patient Name

then wardconfig file open but Patient name is blant, it must be autoselected Patient name

view this image [When click on assign bed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJN64.png)

[but Patient name is blant, it must be autoselected Patient name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdDdd.png)

> models.py Patient model

```
class Patient(Auditable):
aadhar_no = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True,unique=True)
fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
middlename = models.CharField(max_length=30)
lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30)

CATEGORY_GENDER= (('Male', 'Male'), ('Female', 'Female'))
gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=CATEGORY_GENDER)
CATEGORY_BG= (('Not known','Not known'),('A+', 'A+'), ('A-', 'A-'),('B+', 'B+'),('B-', 'B-'),('AB+', 'AB+'),('AB-','AB-'),('O+','O+'), ('O-','O-'))
blood_group = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CATEGORY_BG)
dob = models.DateField()  #Date of birth
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="Patient/", null=True, blank=True)
education = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
CATEGORY_OCC= (('Service', 'Service'), ('Retired', 'Retired'),('Housewife', 'Housewife'), ('Business','Business'),('other','other'))
occupation = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=CATEGORY_OCC,null=True, blank=True) #service, retired, Housewife, Business, others 
current_address = models.TextField()
mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
mobile_number2 = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
country = models.ForeignKey(Country , null=True, blank=True, )
state = models.ForeignKey(State , null=True, blank=True)
district = models.ForeignKey(District , null=True, blank=True)
city = models.ForeignKey(City ,null=True, blank=True)
recreational_drugs= models.BooleanField(default=False) #alocohol, smoking,coffine etc.
current_insurance = models.BooleanField(default=False)
#family = models.ForeignKey(Family) # Family
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
   # return self.fullname
    return str(self.fullname) 
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Patient"
```

> models.py WardConfog

```
class WardConfig(Auditable):
bed = models.ForeignKey(Bed)
ward = models.ForeignKey(Ward)
patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
#def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
    #return self.name
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Wardconfig"
```

> Views.py PatientCreate(CreateView)

class PatientCreate(CreateView):
    model = Patient
    form_class = PatientForm

```
def get_success_url(self): 
    return reverse_lazy( 'patient')

def form_valid(self,PatientForm):
    PatientForm.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

def form_invalid(self, PatientForm):
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=PatientForm))
```

> Views.py

```
class WardConfig(Auditable):
bed = models.ForeignKey(Bed)
ward = models.ForeignKey(Ward)
patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
#def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
    #return self.name
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Wardconfig"
```

please Guys Help me how auto select Patient Name IN Wardconfig  when assign bed

Sorry for English

Comment: you need to add code to explain more

Comment: Can you post your view code?

Comment: Please View **Answer**

Comment: You need to edit your original question with that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the view you are using to add a WardConfig record a `get_initial` method. This assumes you are passing a patient_id kwarg in the URL:

```
def get_initial(self):
    patient = get_object_or_404(Patient, pk=self.kwargs.get('patient_id'))
    return {
        'patient': patient,
    }
```

Comment: hello,it shows error  Page not found (404) No Patient matches the given query.  this code is in patient_list.html  **<li><a href="{% url "add-wardconfig" patient.id %}">Assign Bed</a></li>**

Comment: @Sangram can you update your question with your urls.py and the full code of the view?

Comment: Views.py code link ---> http://pastebin.com/63dcWvRs                                                                        urls.py link ---> http://pastebin.com/SVjghgBa

Comment: @Sangram change `(?P<pk>\d+)` in your add-wardconfig URL to `(?P<patient_id>\d+)` .